# How to add a number to an int thats and not place it next to it

Tags: c#, winforms, integer, counter

i am trying to code a counter for a social project im working on. i am using a windows form. i used a textbox to get my starting digit and a start and stop button.

code wise i manege to make it send the messges and everything but im running into a problem on the counting part. i get the errore of *cant convert int into a string* or it will add a number onto the already existing number example of what it sends: 1, 11, 111, 1111. instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on

this is the part were im messing up on

```
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 1;
            SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

and here is the whole code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Counting_Bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 1;
            SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

im sorry for the bad wording and formating but im new here ¬.¬

Comment: if you are sure that input will be a number then ( textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + 1).ToString();  )

Comment: You can use `NumericUpDown` to allow entering numbers only.

Comment: @Sinatr which however won´t magically convert the text to `int`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, it has `decimal` [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value) property.

Answer (score 0):

The content within your textbox is a `string`, not an `int`. The `+`-operator for strings is implemented in a way that just **concatenates** the string to the end of the first one. So `"1" + "1"`  returns `"11"`, as `"Hello " + "World"` returns `"Hello World"`.

You have to convert your text to a number first:

```
if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var number)
{
    textBox1.Text = (number + 1).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`textBox1.Text` is of type `string`, therefore `+` concatenates `textBox1.Text` and `1` (which is implicitly converted to `string`).

You need to parse `textBox1.Text` as an integer:

```
textBox1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + 1).ToString();
```

Now `+` performs a mathematical addition.

You probably also want to validate your input, to ensure a valid integer has been entered:

```
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int i))
{
    textBox1.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: i am certin that my input is going to be a number becouse im the only person who is using this and i did a validation system _if you look at the last void_ but again using your peice of adivice it still would just go 1, 22, 222, 2222.

Comment: @Probler This should be done within your `timer1_Tick` method. If you're sure that `textBox1.Text` will always be an integer then go ahead and use the first example :)

Comment: `        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                textBox1.Text = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + 1).ToString();
                SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text);
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + 1;
                SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);


        }` 
i did this in the timer tick but it led to the same problem

Answer (score 0):

While the operator is editing the text box, he should be able to make mistakes like typing letters, or even removing everything, as long as you are certain that the operator typed a number when he is finished and presses the button to notify you that he is finished.

Usually you let the operator know that the input is not correct by disabling this button. If the button is enabled, then you know in your button-clicked event handler that the Text in the button is the textual representation of a number.

- Subscribe to event TextBox.TextChanged to enable and disable the button
- Subscribe to event Button.Clicked to process the typed text

The following is usually done using the visual studio designer:

```
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
Button button1 = new Button();

textBox1.TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;
button1.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
```

In your form:

```
int parsedInput = 0;
private void OnTextBoxChanged(object sender, ...)
{
    // get the input text
    string input = textBox1.Text;

    // try to parse the input text. If this can be done, remember the parsedInput
    // enable the button if the input is parsed correctly
    button1.Enabled = (Int32.TryParse(input, out parsedInput);
}

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // Because the button is enabled, you know that parsedInput contains the parsed text
    this.ProcessInput(this.parsedInput);
}
private int GetInput()
{
    Int32.TryParse(input, out int i);
```